# xSpanner: how leader sync data to replicas?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, distributed-transactions, google-cloud-spanner, paxos, data-consistency

In [Spanner: Google’s Globally-Distributed Database](http://research.google.com/archive/spanner.html), section 2.1, we read:

> To support replication, each spanserver implements a single Paxos state machine on top of each tablet. (An early Spanner incarnation supported multiple Paxos state machines per tablet, which allowed for more flexible replication configurations. The complexity of that design led us to abandon it.)
>
> The Paxos state machines are used to implement a consistently replicated bag of mappings.

Does this single Paxos state machine is similar as "Paxos Made Simple" mentioned Paxos state machine?

I'm curious about once a new leader elected how to learn all the data which is lost. Anyone can describe the detail implementation of Paxos group in Spanner?

Answer (score 1):

No data is lost since Spanner uses synchronous replication. Leaders have no state that needs to be transferred if they fail or become unavailable. The worst that would happen is a transaction may need to be retried or fail, such as during an extended partition. Such partitions are incredibly rare due to the underlying infrastructure that Spanner is built on top of (its properties are derived from the union of software & hardware).

Leaders typically have 10 seconds leases that are extended if they prove to be healthy, which means leaders my be reelected every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner on Google Cloud Platform is the same Spanner from the whitepaper and it provides more details about it's custom Paxos implementation. Eric Brewer, the author of CAP Theorem, wrote up a whitepaper on it:

https://research.google.com/pubs/pub45855.html

==

To understand partitions, we need to know a little bit more about how Spanner works. As with most ACID
databases, Spanner uses two-phase commit (2PC) and strict two-phase locking to ensure isolation and
strong consistency. 2PC has been called the “anti-availability” protocol [Hel16] because all members must
be up for it to work. Spanner mitigates this by having each member be a Paxos group, thus ensuring each
2PC “member” is highly available even if some of its Paxos participants are down. Data is divided into
groups that form the basic unit of placement and replication.

==